# Drawing of building outlines (rooftops) based on low resolution aerial images

Tags: aerial-photography, outline

Google maps provides street and rooftop maps from corresponding aerial imagery, but not for all places.

Please is there a method or available software to help outline rooftops from a set of map-tiles, for areas not covered by Google maps?

[image]

how to convert to this?

[image]

Comment: Is using another imagery resource an option?

Comment: sure, if it covers the area of interest

Comment: @DirkBrunken but why does the imagery source matter?

Comment: I thought its part of the problem, because of low resolution? What do you mean then by not covered by google maps? Sorry, i accidentally posted an answer via the app. so, your aim is to add buildings from the satellite imagery to the street view?

Comment: yes, for  example see this:https://www.google.com/maps/place/6%C2%B019'41.4%22N+8%C2%B006'21.1%22E/@6.332074,8.0837086,449m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d6.328175!4d8.105859 

it has quite good aerial views of building but no corresponding outline for the buildings on the street view

Comment: @DirkBrunken my aim is to get building outlines for places that Google map has not covered, but have quite good imagery available , like the link I provided in the comment above, also this link: https://www.google.com/maps/place/6%C2%B019'41.4%22N+8%C2%B006'21.1%22E/@6.3262442,8.1139314,460m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d6.328175!4d8.105859